# Magento 2: wrap multiple elements on the cart page in a Bootstrap 3 panel

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I have wrapped the shopping cart form in a Bootstrap 3 panel by copying `form.phtml` to

> app/design/frontend/{Company}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

and editing the file as folows:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Shopping Cart Items'); ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cart table-wrapper<?php echo $mergedCells == 2 ? ' detailed' : ''; ?>">
            <form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>"
                  method="post"
                  id="form-validate"
                  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
                  class="form form-cart">
                <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                <table id="shopping-cart-table"
                       class="cart items data table"
                       data-mage-init='{"shoppingCart":{"emptyCartButton": "action.clear",
                   "updateCartActionContainer": "#update_cart_action_container"}}'>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col item" scope="col"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                echo __('Item') ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                echo __('Price') ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col qty" scope="col"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                echo __('Qty') ?></span></th>
                        <th class="col subtotal" scope="col"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                echo __('Subtotal') ?></span></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="cart main actions text-center">
                    <?php if ($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
                        <a class="action continue btn btn-primary"
                           href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>"
                           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')); ?>">
                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                echo __('Continue Shopping') ?></span>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <button type="submit"
                            name="update_cart_action"
                            data-cart-empty=""
                            value="empty_cart"
                            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')); ?>"
                            class="action clear btn btn-primary" id="empty_cart_button">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo __('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit"
                            name="update_cart_action"
                            data-cart-item-update=""
                            value="update_qty"
                            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')); ?>"
                            class="action update btn btn-primary">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                            echo __('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" value="" id="update_cart_action_container" data-cart-item-update=""/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have moved the *cart summary* below the cart *products list* by writing this line of code `<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.items" after="checkout.cart.form"/>` in

> app/design/frontend/{Company}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

[image]

But I did not manage to wrap everything in the Bootstrap 3 panel to make it look like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below line in **form.phtml** where you want to show cart summary:

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('cart.summary') ?>
```

In **checkout_cart_index.xml** in your theme:

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.form" />
```

Try it, write me about result.